# CI 2 - Language class and models

Tags: codeigniter-2, php-5.2

I noticed an odd issue and I can't seem to find anything to explain it.

on one of my models i add an error output message to alert that a record is not available, but when it outputs, i get no text, just a blank page.

Now the language tags are valid, the only thing i can figure is that the language file isn't meant to be used on a model, if thats the case I don't see that being explained anywhere.

I hope someone can help me get in the right direction on this, if i have to just set it to false and handle the message on the ui, I'll do that, but prefer not to.

Thanks.

EDIT:

here is what a quick code snipplet that should help:

```
//fetch topic data.
$this->db->select('id, Name, Description, Level');
$this->db->from('groups');
$this->db->where('id', $gid);
$query = $this->db->get();
$GroupData = $query->row();

//see if we have any records to show.
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $this->setId($GroupData->id);
    $this->setName($GroupData->Name);
    $this->setDescription($GroupData->Description);
    $this->setLevel($GroupData->Level);
} else {
    //no record was found, throw an error.
    show_error($this->lang->line('invalidgid').'<hr />File:'.__FILE__.'<br />Line:'.__LINE__, 500, $this->lang->line('error'));
    log_message('error', 'invalid GroupID was provided.'); //log error in error log.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb, but I figured it out, the language file hasn't loaded yet at that point, ARGH!

I will have to go back to the drawing board on this one it looks, any suggestions, please post them.